# XML tag still being printed even if it is blank (xml version="1.0" encoding='utf-8')

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

I have an inquiry regarding the XSL script I am currently working on.

The script is running and no error is being encountered, however, my issue is on some of the fields wherein they were not supposed to be printed.

See snippet below:

```
<xsl:if test="not(Payee/RemitAdviceEmail='')">
<RltdRmtInf>
<RmtLctnMtd>
<xsl:text>EMAL</xsl:text>
</RmtLctnMtd>
<RmtLctnElctrncAdr>
<xsl:value-of select="Payee/RemitAdviceEmail"/>
</RmtLctnElctrncAdr>
</RltdRmtInf>
</xsl:if>
```

Since I have the condition that if the Payee/RemitAdviceEmail is NOT blank, then the following will be printed in the xml.

```
<RltdRmtInf>
<RmtLctnMtd>EMAL</RmtLctnMtd>
<RmtLctnElctrncAdr>abcdef.ghijk@email.com</RmtLctnElctrncAdr>
</RltdRmtInf>
```

Whilst, if Payee/RemitAdviceEmail is blank then the whole RltdRmtInf will not be printed.

However, on the xml for the recent run I had using this script, I am getting this result instead:

```
<RltdRmtInf>
<RmtLctnMtd>EMAL</RmtLctnMtd>
<RmtLctnElctrncAdr/>
</RltdRmtInf>
```

I checked the xml to locate the Payee/RemitAdviceEmail xpath, and I confirmed that the RemitAdviceEmail is not even existing under Payee or all over the xml. Since it is not existing, should the whole RltdRmtInf not be printed as well?

Appreciate your response on this.

Thank you everyone!

Expected output:

whole tag should not be printed on the xml

Actual output:

```
<RltdRmtInf>
<RmtLctnMtd>EMAL</RmtLctnMtd>
<RmtLctnElctrncAdr/>
</RltdRmtInf>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I confirmed that the RemitAdviceEmail is not even existing

That is the problem with your test. When an element does not exist, the expression:

```
element=''
```

returns `false`, and consequently:

```
not(element='')
```

returns `true`.

---

Try changing your test to:

```
<xsl:if test="Payee/RemitAdviceEmail/text()">
```

Answer (score -1):

In XSLT, an empty result is still a result. This means that even if the condition inside the `<xsl:if>` statement evaluates to false and the elements inside are not populated, they will still be output as empty elements in the resulting XML.

To prevent the entire `<RltdRmtInf>` element from being output when the condition is not met, you should encapsulate the entire block within the `<xsl:if>` statement. Here's how you can modify your XSLT to achieve the desired behavior:

```
    <xsl:if test="not(Payee/RemitAdviceEmail='')">
    <RltdRmtInf>
        <RmtLctnMtd>EMAL</RmtLctnMtd>
        <RmtLctnElctrncAdr>
            <xsl:value-of select="Payee/RemitAdviceEmail"/>
        </RmtLctnElctrncAdr>
    </RltdRmtInf>
</xsl:if>
```

This way, if the condition is not met (i.e., Payee/RemitAdviceEmail is blank or does not exist), the entire `<RltdRmtInf>` element and its children will not be output in the resulting XML.

Comment: Look more carefully: OP's code **does** encapsulate the entire block within the `<xsl:if`> statement.